# When building certain GNU software from source, the man page installs are missing. How can I get them?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu, tar

Although I have experienced this with several GNU utilities already, let me give a specific example. I tried to install `tar-1.30`, which was downloaded from:

https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.30.tar.xz

The official gnu ftp (via http). I build it from source after configuring without any issues. However the install-man make rule is missing even from the Makefile.in that comes with tar. Here are all of the documentation targets right from the `Makefile.in` file, with the newlines between them removed for brevity:

```
dvi: dvi-recursive
dvi-am:
html: html-recursive
html-am:
info: info-recursive
info-am:
install-data-am:
install-dvi: install-dvi-recursive
install-dvi-am:
install-exec-am:
install-html: install-html-recursive
install-html-am:
install-info: install-info-recursive
install-info-am:
install-man:                             <==
install-pdf: install-pdf-recursive
install-pdf-am:
install-ps: install-ps-recursive
install-ps-am:
```

Notice that the `install-man` target (to which I added a <== so it is easy to find) leads nowhere (i.e., has no further dependencies), thus causing no man pages to be created. The `info` pages, on the other hand, get created just fine, because the install-info leads to install-info-recursive and actual steps to build them down the line.

`install-man` is mentioned in the `.PHONY` line as indicated by the <==, below:

```
.PHONY: $(am__recursive_targets) CTAGS GTAGS TAGS all all-am \
    am--refresh check check-am clean clean-cscope clean-generic \
    cscope cscopelist-am ctags ctags-am dist dist-all dist-bzip2 \
    dist-gzip dist-hook dist-lzip dist-shar dist-tarZ dist-xz \
    dist-zip distcheck distclean distclean-generic distclean-hdr \
    distclean-local distclean-tags distcleancheck distdir \
    distuninstallcheck dvi dvi-am html html-am info info-am \
    install install-am install-data install-data-am install-dvi \
    install-dvi-am install-exec install-exec-am install-html \
    install-html-am install-info install-info-am install-man \       <==
    install-pdf install-pdf-am install-ps install-ps-am \
    install-strip installcheck installcheck-am installdirs \
    installdirs-am maintainer-clean maintainer-clean-generic \
    mostlyclean mostlyclean-generic pdf pdf-am ps ps-am tags \
    tags-am uninstall uninstall-am
```

..., but it (i.e., `install-man`) is a do-nothing build step. Why is this and how do I get `man` pages installed when building `tar` and other GNU utilities that have an empty `install-man` target?

Comment: Tell the GNU project to write man pages for their software?

Comment: They already did, they should be built from the same files from which the `info` files and other documentation types get built. The man page is available via we access - it exists. The question is why can it not be built using the normal well known mechanism of `install-man`?

Comment: Do you mean "web access"? If so, that's just the info page in HTML format, not a man page.

Comment: I thought many projects switched to textinfo, and now you use `info` instead. Man pages are sometimes supplied for pedantic/archaic reasons. Instead of dumping the makefile you should probably look at `./configure --help`. `configure.ac` may have some goodness to write the rules on the fly or dynamically remove them. One of my `configure.ac` writes them on the fly as needed. (I prefer man pages, too. Old habit from the 1990s).